# Add people to a friend list using Facebook JavaScript SDK?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am creating a Facebook application using the Facebook JavaScript SDK. The application has the functionality to create friend lists. I previously created a test friend list and inserted the list ID and comma separated String of some friend IDs. The Facebook developers example to add friends to a list returns the following error by console.log():

```
Object {error: Object}
error: Object
code: 100
message: "(#100) Requires one of the params: member,members"
type: "OAuthException"
```

The JS SDK example code can be found here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/friendlist/members

```
FB.api(
   "/{friendlist-id}/members",
   "POST",
   {
       "object": {
           "members": "{user-id-1}, {user-id-2}"
       }
   },
   function (response) {
     if (response && !response.error) {
       /* handle the result */
     }
   }
);
```

Note I replaced the {} placeholders with the required IDs. Example: "/8748754873/members/" and "members": "23445565, 145436356"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer was simple, the parameters are not nested in another Object. The Object has to be flat:

```
FB.api(
   "/{friendlist-id}/members",
   "POST",
   {
       "members": "{user-id-1}, {user-id-2}"
   },
   function (response) {
     if (response && !response.error) {
       /* handle the result */
     }
   }
);
```